# to display all records from one table and sum of rows from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables HouseKeeping with fields RoomNo,FloorNo,StockItem,Requirement and Stock table with fields Item ,Available.I want to select all rows from HouseKeeping table and sum of requirement from stock table.I have used this query to get sum of requirement from stock table

`SELECT SUM(Requirement) AS Requirement, StockItem
FROM  HouseKeeping
GROUP BY StockItem`

in addition to this i also want all records(select * from Stock).How to do it? please reply as soon as possible.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

`JOIN` the two tables like so:

```
SELECT h.stockItem, SUM(h.Requirement)
FROM HouseKeeping h 
INNER JOIN Stock s ON h.stockItem = s.Item
GROUP BY h.stockItem
```

This will give you all the sum of all the `Requirement` values for only the item that has a `Requirement` in the other table `stock`.

If you want to include those non matching items, i.e: with no item in the `stock` table. Use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of the `INNER JOIN` with `ISNULL(SUM(h.Requirement)` to set a 0 instead of `NULL`.

Comment: I recommend a left join so that you get items that maybe in H and not S. It will cover the case of the inner join so it's safer without any extra overhead.

Comment: here is the querySELECT        s.Item, s.Available, SUM(h.Requirement) AS Requirement
FROM            Stock AS s LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         HouseKeeping AS h ON h.StockItem = s.Item
GROUP BY s.Item, s.Available